# VSCODE Indentation with PHPIntellisense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, format, indentation

I'm working in a team and not everyone use the same indentation format, so I'd like to have the chance to select only a portion of code and indent only that. It would be nice to have the same keybinding for selection indentation and all documents indentation. In past I was using Netbeans and without any setting was working fine.
Any recommendation is appreciated

Thanks guys :)

Comment: I'd venture to suggest that your team should agree on a consistent format, but that's not a software issue

Answer (score 0):

I've found this.
Indent all document (which is default option):

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+f",
  "command": "editor.action.formatDocument",
  "when": "editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !inCompositeEditor"
}
```

Indent only selection:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+d",
  "command": "editor.action.formatSelection",
  "when": "editorHasDocumentSelectionFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

I managed to change keybinding for each action.